# Qml in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, qt, qml

I Have created a program using qml in Qt. Here it is working fine. But when  I am trying to  run the same app in the visual studio it is not. There is no error in building the program in Visual Studio. When I run the  program using "F5" its  running  & closing automatically with out showing any thing.

What could be the error???

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was that the debugger of the visual studio runs in a different path than the output is.
So I had to adjust in the project properties the "Working Directory" of the debugger.

Comment: ok fine...when I imported the .pro file it is working..but in the case I am making the app its is not.